# File is empty and CORS problem when I upload a file from React front-end to Azure Data Lake Storage (ADLS) Gen2

Tags: azure, file-upload, cors, azure-data-lake

I have problems with this uploading to Azure.
Structure on the server is like '{workspaceId}/{requestId}/Raw/{fileName}.csv'
The browser makes two call. The first returns 201 Created, but the second CORS problem. The screenshot of the both call are below.
BUT the file is created on the server with the correct name, but this file is empty.
I opened all request methods on the server like PUT/MERGE/POST and so on.
Any ideas how to fix?

```
    import { DataLakeServiceClient } from '@azure/storage-file-datalake'

    ...

    const onUpload = async (file: File) => {

        // Getting upload link
        const endpointData = await getUploadEndpoint()

        const dataLakeServiceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(`${endpointData.data}`)
        const requestId = dataLakeServiceClient.url.split('/')[4]
        const subFolderName = 'Raw'

        const containerClient = dataLakeServiceClient.getFileSystemClient('')    
        const fileClient = containerClient.getFileClient(file.name)

        const options = {
              pathHttpHeaders: { contentType: file.type }
        }

        // Trying to upload a file
        try {
            await fileClient.upload(file, { ...options })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error:', error)
        }
    }
```

The first call, returns 201

[image]

The second CORS problem. I see the differenct in URL is &position=0&action=append

[image]

CORS setting on the server:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include the CORS settings.

Comment: @GauravMantri Added the screenshot with the cors settings. Thank you!

Comment: What about exposed headers?

Comment: @GauravMantri updated the image with the settings. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your request is failing is because the append operation uses `PATCH` HTTP Verb which you do not have as allowed methods in your CORS settings.

Please try by adding `PATCH` HTTP verb in CORS settings and you should not get the error.

For more details, please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/update